# How to use nginx PAM module?

Tags: nginx, authentication, freebsd, pam

I would like to use nginx [PAM module](http://web.iti.upv.es/~sto/nginx/) to authenticate a site with existing users on a FreeBSD system. I tried to use pam_unix.so, but no luck. It's just not let me in with my usr/psw pair. :(

nginx conf:

```
location / {
        root html;
        auth_pam               "Secure Zone";
        auth_pam_service_name  "nginx";
        fastcgi_pass           127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index          index.php;
        fastcgi_param          SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include                fastcgi_params;
    }
```

The nginx file in the `/usr/local/etc/pam.d` dir:

```
auth    required     pam_unix.so
account required     pam_unix.so
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell me a working configuration. :)

Comment: Can you also add some logs of what's going on from nginx perspective? Depending on your OS you can also find some clues in /var/log/auth.log or similar file.

Answer (score 7):

Answer to a very old question, but I was able to confirm that this does work so this might help.  This allows an nginx location to be authenticated against the local server account names.  YMMV.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- nginx 1.14 (which includes the http_auth_pam module)

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Create `/etc/pam.d/nginx` and add the line:

```
@include common-auth
```

Within your nginx config:

```
location /secure {
        auth_pam                "Secure zone";
        auth_pam_service_name   "nginx";
}
```

and the magic sauce is:

```
sudo usermod -aG shadow www-data
```

Check in the nginx.conf for the account used in with the `user www-data`. It can sometimes be configured to `nobody`.

Restart nginx and bingo!

*Thanks to the answers above that helped me complete this solution*

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you've already tried this, but I did notice here:

> Note that the module runs as the web server user, so the PAM modules
>   used must be able to authenticate the users without being root; that
>   means that if you want to use the pam_unix.so module to autenticate
>   users you need to let the web server user to read the /etc/shadow file
>   if that does not scare you (on Debian like systems you can add the
>   www-data user to the shadow group).

[Nginx HTTP Auth PAM Module README](http://web.iti.upv.es/~sto/nginx/ngx_http_auth_pam_module-1.2/README.html)

I can't confirm your config I'm afraid as I'm not using pam_unix.so.

Comment: I tried to add www group read permission to the /etc/master.passwd (the FreeBSD equivalent of /etc/shadow as far as i know.) But still i can't be authenticated with my user :( (the nginx processes are run by root default)