# nginx http authentication with system user

Tags: linux, nginx, .htpasswd

I'm running a nginx server with basic http authentication that use a htpasswd password file.
Is possible use instead the normal user and passwpord of linux system?

Comment: You can use the nginx PAM module: cf. [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/372719/how-to-use-nginx-pam-module)

Comment: thanks that's works!
I've also been added:
    `auth optional pam_faildelay.so delay=3000000`
    `auth required pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup secureGroup`
To allow access only for user in the specified group.