# Protect file in nginx using Linux user authentication

Tags: linux, nginx, security, authentication

I'm interested in protecting a specific file served by nginx. I know that this can be done with password as described [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/).

I'm wondering if this can also be done using Linux user authentication, i.e., the credentials of existing users of the server machine (maybe some of them that belong to a specific group?). I'm totally new to nginx (and to any other web servers), so accept my apologies and lend some helping hand if you wish.

Comment: try this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/957150/383126)